# How to add icons on the KDE Menu Editor icon source?

Tags: kde, plasma, kde5

I want to know the location of items of these two options:

- System icons
- Other icons

I do not know how to add icons to the list. How to do?

[image]

Comment: Check out `\usr\share\icons` for various icon themes and `\usr\share\hicolor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something which has frustrated me for a long time.

You should be able to right click on any icon and get the path to it, but that hasn't been implemented.

Since you haven't received a good answer, I'll give you a few clues.

Here are some places icons live:

```
/usr/share/app-install/icons
/usr/share/icons
/usr/local/share/icons
/usr/share/pixmaps
```

You can browse through them in `Dolphin` with `Show Previews of Files and Folders` turned on. Then, you'll see how they render.

You could, theoretically, add your new icons in these locations, but they might get deleted when you do software updates and upgrades. They will certainly be gone sooner or later when you do a clean install.

What I do instead is to save all my favorite icons (including some from the above locations) separately - especially because several that I really liked went away in newer releases. Now I put them in my own directory.

```
/home/my-user/icons
```

That way I can keep them no matter what I or the developers decide to do.

Then, when I want to use one from the icon dialog, I select `Other Icons` and `Browse` and go to the directory where I have them saved.